# Minimum amount of Nodes in Redis Cluster

Tags: redis

From what I have read,

> Note that the minimal cluster that works as expected requires to contain at least three master nodes. For your first tests it is strongly suggested to start a six nodes cluster with three masters and three slaves.

[redis cluster tutorial](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial)

Why is the suggest cluster need to contain 6 nodes. Why is 6 the magic number and not 3?